# Merge or extend JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the values of several input fields and then displaying those values somewhere else on the page using JS functions. I will have 10 input fields, therefore is there a way I can optimize my JS code and write a function to loop through the values of the input fields and display them afterwards? Here are two functions which I wrote for two different fields:

```
function gotoTask() {
    var message = document.getElementById("goto").value;
    goto_message.innerHTML = message;
}

function waitTask() {
    var message = document.getElementById("wait").value;
    wait_message.innerHTML = message;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to display all the messages together?

Comment: Answered already in ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @Unmitigated like this in an HTML file.

`Task: <span id="goto_message"></span> <span id="wait_message"></span>`

Comment: you asked a thing and showed the code for something else.. I mean if you want to factor your logic so that it loops through some elements and repeat the same action just do `document.querySelectorAll('input')` (I used the selector `input` but you didn't give enough details for that) and fetch all the returned elements to do anything you need to do with them

Comment: You can store the ids in a list and loop through them and call the function you want to perform dynamically using template literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a curry/factory function:

```
function createTaskFn(el, messageElId) {
   return function() {
    var message = document.getElementById(messageElId).value;
    el.innerHTML = message;
   };
}

var gotoTask = crateTaskFn(goto_message, 'goto');
var waitTask = crateTaskFn(wait_message, 'wait');
```

Comment: So should I simply call the createTaskFn on every button click? How would it get which button has been clicked and which message to display?

Answer (score 0):

Give same class to your all inputs , then select them by let inputArr = document.getElementsByClassName('inputsClass') , then loop through inputArr and display their values.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the ids in an array like so

```
const inputIds = ['goto', 'wait', ...]
```

Then you can iterate over that array and call your method like so

```
inputIds.forEach((id) => {
   const message = document.getElementById(id).value;
   document.getElementById(`${id}_message`).innerHTML = message;
})
```

Disadvantage of my implementation: Your ids of the message fields have to have the same structure [id]_message

Comment: I want to display the input only when a button is clicked. Each input field has a separate button. Can I make this using an onclick function?

Comment: So you don't want to execute the function for all 10 inputs at once? So every input has a button and if the user clicks on the button only one input field function gets executed. Right?

Comment: Exactly. Every input has a separate button.

Comment: Ok so I misunderstood your requirements. My implementation will execute for all 10 inputs at once. So I would suggest to use @Daniel A. White answer and call his method on every onclick handler